# Help with flash collision detection. Rotating and hiting at the same time

Tags: flash, collision-detection

What I want to do is rotate the object and have its collision box rotate with it. I want the rectangle to rotate so it looks like a diamond and have one of its sides hit the object in a per pixel fashion. From my reading of some books and websites it seems that normal rectangular collision and hitTestObject collision won't do for this problem. I have searched high and low and want to know if anyone has a solution to hit detection with moving and rotating objects. Here is my current collision code with rectangles

```
colboxrect = colbox1.getRect(this);
robotrect = robot1.getRect(this);
if(robotrect.intersects(colboxrect))
{
   velocity *=-1;
}
```

What I want to happen is when it collides the robot will bounce off of the box. It works but only when it hits it head on. I want it to rotate and be able to hit. I am looking for the flash equivalent of this basically.
http://creators.xna.com/en-US/tutorial/collision2dperpixeltransformed

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use BitmapData's [hitTest()](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#hitTest%28%29) method for that. Here a few articles on that by Adobe's Mike Chambers:

- [Using BitmapData.hitTest for Collision Detection](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/06/24/using-bitmapdata-hittest-for-collision-detection/)
- [Strategies for optimizing collision detection with BitmapData.hitTest](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/06/25/strategies-for-optimizing-collision-detection-with-bitmapdata-hittest/)
- [Relative performance for collision detection techniques in ActionScript 3](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/06/26/relative-performance-for-collision-detection-techniques-in-actionscript-3/)

The pixel perfect technique is around for some time. 
Grant Skinner wrote an [as2 version](http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2005/10/source_code_sha.html) in the flash 8 days.
There are [ports to as3](http://labs.boulevart.be/index.php/2007/06/08/skinner-collision-detection-in-as3/) obviously.

Corey O'Neil wrote the [Collision Detection Kit](http://www.coreyoneil.com/portfolio/index.php?project=5), you might want to have a look.

HTH,
George